# Looking for a quad low side power driver IC

Tags: driver

We have been using the Allegro UDQ2559LB. This is a quad (4 channel) low side power driver (used to drive relay and lamp loads) with about 0.5 amp per channel capability and overload, short circuit, and over temperature protection. Allegro is shutting their fab and discontinuing this part. Any one have suggestions for a good replacement? 4 channels would be ideal and the part must be surface mount.

Answer (score 1):

[This part](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/auips2051.pdf) and [this one](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ips1051.pdf) from IR are dual channel drivers in an SO-8 package. You maybe could use two of these.